# react-date-picker in Material ui Dialog Cuts off datepicker

Tags: css, dialog, material-ui

Hi I'm having Datepicker (based on the react-date-picker package) inside Material ui Dialog.Dialog works perfectly but When i click on datepicker it scrolling down and cuts off and scroll showing.

this is my  [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-clarke-eihnq?file=/src/App.js) 
how do i overcome this with css

overflow scroll couldn't solved the issue because i'm having a list item

Comment: I'm really sorry for that please click on Ctrl+Shift+D or toggle preview ,use can edit /copy as you need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. Note this only work for some cases. Because the cut off issue has only happened to the first row in my case. You can fix with first child in CSS

I have applied the position to the calendar only when it at first child

```
.react-calendar {

position: fixed !important;
top: calc(100% - 479px) !important;

}
```

if you are having an issue, please Modify your modal first . This only happens using on modal.

I'm just a beginner to CSS so this one came first and it worked for me . Thanks @Dekel

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `react-date-picker` combined with the `material-ui`'s `<Dialog>` component, and the problem is that the date-picker is rendered inside the Dialog's DOM, so it's blocked to the visible part of the dialog.

Based on the API of react-date-picker there is no way to change the element to render date-picker box, so one option is to use another date picker.

You can use the material-pickers component:

```
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import { DatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

<Dialog open={true} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText>
      Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used
      in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is
      attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century
    </DialogContentText>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogActions>
    <Button>ok</Button>
  </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-datepicker-inside-dialog-i6wts
You can find all the options for the material datepicker in the [API docs](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/DatePicker).

Comment: We have already used this data picker entirely for project ,We couldn't roll back that why i posted the question .Do we need to style datepicker instead by giving position .Any other way?

Comment: You can wrap the DatePicker in another Modal and use this component instead, but you will need to manage the opening of the modal yourself. How hard is it to refactor your code and move to another component? It should be pretty easy.

Comment: Hi I have fixed the issue by adding Position fixed and top to datepicker .While checking the issue is occuring for first list so applied css to the first list item,Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, my fix was to set a max-height on the picker root:

`.MuiYearPicker-root{ max-height: 200px; }`

this keeps the picker dialog above the text field, instead of below, and stops its from being cut off by the modal its in.